# Get facebook comments with the graph api without user authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I'm building a flex application using the http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ library.
Is it possible to get all the comments for an OBJECT_ID (https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments) without the current user being logged in facebook. If it is, please tell me what the OBJECT_ID needs to be (post in public group or something else).

Thanks in advance.
blz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request the offline_access permission. It will give you an access token that won't expire. Save it in your database and use it for your connections and it will work without the user.

More: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

I believe Object_ID is the user, and they do not have to be logged in for you to acquire this

But...

What you probably will require is authentication of your request. I believe FB now requires that you register your webapp with them to get the necessary OAUTH signature. I think this is as of F8 2010.

Comment: What i think is that Object_ID is a post-id. It's something like: 133291076729199_166951123363194 (userID_postID probably). I have my application authenticated (init) and i think i get a FacebookSession but no comments are returned if i'm not logged in with a user. I'm still testing..